# How i can check sex types (M or F) when read xml file

Tags: c#, xml, radio-button, xmlreader

good night. At my solution i have an code that allow me write 5 useful informations about user, like: name, sex, age, weight and height. When was implemented solution to check if sex was M or F i used these code

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                value = radioButton1.Text;
                Convert.ToString(value);


            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                value = radioButton2.Text;
                Convert.ToString(value);
            }
```

value is an variable as string type. Now i need an similar code to read, i think that is similar, and i start, building an new class. With the open class, i started by declaring the necessary variables, prepare the constructor and set methods. I have an method called getxmlusersex (), which is specific for sex verification in existing xml and this method have the following code (imagined and planned by me)

```
  public void getxmlusersex()
        {
            add.sex = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Dados//Sexo").InnerText;
            if (add.sex == "M")
            {
                add.sex = form.radioButton1.Text;
                Convert.ToBoolean(form.radioButton1.Text);
            }
            if (add.sex == "F")
            {
                add.sex = form.radioButton2.Text;
                Convert.ToBoolean(form.radioButton2.Text);
            }


        }
```

When running and check if user exists, the solution print name, age, weight and height but don't print sex type (M or F). So how can i filter if sex is M or F and check this same radiobutton (radiobutton1 or radiobutton2)

Comment: what kind of variable is `add.sex`?  What is the use of `Convert.ToBoolean(form.radioButton1.Text);` when you don't use its return value?

Comment: i've called an form1 with name form due to radiobuttons

Comment: add is from another class that allow me to insert user

Comment: And the purpose for `Convert.ToBoolean` ?

Comment: I think it asked the type of the sex field, if it's a String, you probably want to trim() before comparing it, and maybe contour lowercase/uppercase differences.

Comment: well i'm beginner in C# ... Maybe i was a little nervous when tried to implement these code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set `RadioButton.Checked` property for proper `RatioButton`. That is how you can achieve this:

```
add.sex = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Dados//Sexo").InnerText;
if (add.sex == "M")
{
    form.radioButton1.Text = "Male"; //if you do not specify text in designer
    form.radioButton1.Checked = true;
}
else if (add.sex == "F")
{
    form.radioButton2.Text = "Female";
    form.radioButton2.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: also take a look on string comparsion tips from @Diego C Nascimento